# Returning object oriented json from sparql queries

Tags: json, sparql

If I want to ask for some different properties A and B, in SPARQL,
where there is one unique A, and possibly several B's belonging to each A.

The resulting query that I get is on the form:

```
A1, B1
A1, B2
A1, B3
A1, B4
A2, B5
```

How I would want this query result to look, is more of the form:

```
A1: B1,B2,B3,B4
A2: B5
```

Is there a way of doing this in SPARQL? What is this called?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JSON output for SPARQL is documented in [SPARQL 1.1 Query Results JSON Format](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-json/), and specifically section [3.2.2 Encoding RDF Terms](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-json/#select-encode-terms) describes how the RDF is encoded in the JSON.  Note that the JSON output is really just for encoding the results of a SPARQL query, not for creating JSON objects that correspond to a particular object model.  Your best bet is probably to take the results you're getting and manipulate them yourself.  There are still a few things that might be helpful from the SPARQL side, though.

### `group_concat` for combining values

That said, maybe the following can help you get something that will work a bit better for you. If you have data like this:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .

:object :hasA1 :b1, :b2, :b3, :b4 ;
        :hasA2 :b5 .
```

and a query like this:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?subject ?property ?object
where {
  values ?property { :hasA1 :hasA2 }
  ?subject ?property ?object .
}
```

you'll get results like:

```
$ arq --data data.n3 --query query.sparql
-------------------------------
| subject | property | object |
===============================
| :object | :hasA1   | :b4    |
| :object | :hasA1   | :b3    |
| :object | :hasA1   | :b2    |
| :object | :hasA1   | :b1    |
| :object | :hasA2   | :b5    |
-------------------------------
```

You can use `group_concat` to combine all the values for `hasA1` into a single value with a query like:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?subject ?property (group_concat(?object;separator=',') as ?cobject)
where {
  values ?property { :hasA1 :hasA2 }
  ?subject ?property ?object .
}
group by ?subject ?property
```

and get results like:

```
$ arq --data data.n3 --query query.sparql
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| subject | property | cobject                                                                                   |
==================================================================================================================
| :object | :hasA2   | "http://example.org/b5"                                                                   |
| :object | :hasA1   | "http://example.org/b4,http://example.org/b3,http://example.org/b2,http://example.org/b1" |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you ask for the results in JSON format, you'll get the following output, which *might* work for you, depending on what kinds of entities your `b1`–`b4` are.  Specifically, if they're strings, where concatenation makes sense, this could be fine.  If they're something else, it's probably not so useful.

```json
$ arq -out JSON --data data.n3 --query query.sparql
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "subject" , "property" , "cobject" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "subject": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://example.org/object" } ,
        "property": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://example.org/hasA2" } ,
        "cobject": { "type": "literal" , "value": "http://example.org/b5" }
      } ,
      {
        "subject": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://example.org/object" } ,
        "property": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://example.org/hasA1" } ,
        "cobject": { "type": "literal" , "value": "http://example.org/b4,http://example.org/b3,http://example.org/b2,http://example.org/b1" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### `group_concat` with `construct`

There are JSON serializations of RDF out there, and while they may not be supported by SPARQL engines, you could use a `construct` query to generate some RDF that is structured more like your desired form, and then use an RDF serialization converter to convert to a JSON format.  For instance, Jena's `rdfcat` supports [RDF/JSON](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-json.html) output.  Using a `construct` query like this:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

construct { 
 ?subject ?property ?cobject
}
where {
  select ?subject ?property (group_concat(?object;separator=',') as ?cobject)
  where {
    values ?property { :hasA1 :hasA2 }
    ?subject ?property ?object .
  }
  group by ?subject ?property 
}
```

(See [Can we combine CONSTRUCT with aggregates in SPARQL 1.1?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/11916/can-we-combine-construct-with-aggregates-in-sparql-11) on answers.semanticweb.com for an explanation of why there's a nested query in this query.)  This generates RDF of the form:

```xml
$ arq --out RDF/XML --data data.n3 --query query.sparql 
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://example.org/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/object">
    <hasA1>http://example.org/b4,http://example.org/b3,http://example.org/b2,http://example.org/b1</hasA1>
    <hasA2>http://example.org/b5</hasA2>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

We can pipe that through `rdfcat` to get some RDF/JSON out, which may finally be closer to what you're looking for:

```json
$ arq --out RDF/XML --data data.n3 --query query.sparql | rdfcat -out RDF/JSON /dev/stdin 
{ 
  "http://example.org/object" : { 
    "http://example.org/hasA2" : [ { 
      "type" : "literal" ,
      "value" : "http://example.org/b5"
    }
     ] ,
    "http://example.org/hasA1" : [ { 
      "type" : "literal" ,
      "value" : "http://example.org/b4,http://example.org/b3,http://example.org/b2,http://example.org/b1"
    }
     ]
  }
}
```